# Installing Modernizr with Yarn on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg

I am trying to install Modernizr with Yarn in Rails.  I do `'yarn add Modernizr'` and it gets added to the .node-modules directory.  However, I can't figure out how to reference it properly from Rails.

I have added `//= require modernizr/src/Modernizr` to application.js.  But I'm not sure that's the right reference because I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

Do I need to somehow build the Modernizr library.  Does yarn not do that?  I'm somewhat new to this and struggling to understand the relationship between webpacker, yarn, and rails and how to properly build and add libraries to rails with yarn.  The tutorials all make it seem as though it's as simple as `'yarn add xxx'` but I seem to be missing something.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you cannot reference webpacker packs in Sprockets (e.g. application.js). You can go the other way around, but not the way you describe. Try setting up a 'pack', import Modernizer into the pack, then reference it with a `javascript_pack_tag`.

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is the [webpacker gem](https://github.com/rails/webpacker), which ships by default with Rails 5.1+ but can be used with Rails 4.2+. Get that set up, then follow these steps to get a custom Modernizr build running in your Rails app:

**Loader**

Install the loader for modernizr:

```
$ yarn install webpack-modernizr-loader
```

**Modernizr Configuration**

Download your desired modernizr config from the modernizr site. Visit a link like this:

https://modernizr.com/download?-appearance-backgroundblendmode-backgroundcliptext-backgroundsize-bgpositionxy-borderradius-boxshadow-boxsizing-canvas-canvastext-cssgradients-csspointerevents-fontface-generatedcontent-inputtypes-lastchild-mediaqueries-multiplebgs-opacity-svg-touchevents-setclasses-dontmin-cssclassprefix:mod_

Then configure your build, click "Build" in the upper right-hand corner, and download "Command Line Config".

Then convert it from JSON to a module and save it as `config/webpack/.modernizrrc.js` (note the leading period in the filename), like so:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
  minify: false,
  options: [
    "setClasses"
  ],
  "feature-detects": [
    "test/canvas",
    "test/canvastext",
    "test/inputtypes",
    "test/svg",
    "test/touchevents",
    "test/css/appearance",
    "test/css/backgroundblendmode",
    "test/css/backgroundcliptext",
    "test/css/backgroundposition-xy",
    "test/css/backgroundsize",
    "test/css/borderradius",
    "test/css/boxshadow",
    "test/css/boxsizing",
    "test/css/fontface",
    "test/css/generatedcontent",
    "test/css/gradients",
    "test/css/lastchild",
    "test/css/mediaqueries",
    "test/css/multiplebgs",
    "test/css/opacity",
    "test/css/pointerevents"
  ]
};
```

**Custom Configuration**

Next, create a custom webpack config file as `config/webpack/custom.js`:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: "webpack-modernizr-loader",
        test: /\.modernizrrc\.js$/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      modernizr$: path.resolve(__dirname, "./.modernizrrc.js")
    }
  }
};
```

**Expose Configuration**

Make your `config/webpack/environment.js` look like this:

```
const { environment } = require("@rails/webpacker");
const customConfig    = require('./custom');

environment.config.merge(customConfig);

module.exports = environment;
```

**Import Modernizr**

Add the following line to `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
import modernizr from 'modernizr';
```

**Load Your Pack**

Add this to your layout:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag "application", defer: true %>
```

**Voila**

Load up your site in a browser, inspect, and confirm that (a) modernizr CSS classes have been added to the DOM, and (b) you aren't seeing any webpack compilation errors in the console.

**Further Reading**

I came upon this question when I was looking to set up modernizr using webpacker in a Rails 5 app, saw the question was unanswered, and figured it out myself. If you want to know how all of this works, I suggest reading the docs for [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md) and [webpack-modernizr-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-modernizr-loader).

Comment: Does it also involve the step of adding the custom modernizr js file from desired custom build into webpack/src directory ? @armchairdj

Comment: The command to install the loader shoudl be `yarn add webpack-modernizr-loader`